# NSCFConstantString text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c

> NSCFConstantString text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

if (self.device) {
    // Update existing device
    [self.device setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
    [self.device setValue:self.versionTextField.text forKey:@"version"];
    [self.device setValue:self.companyTextField.text forKey:@"company"];
    NSLog(@"if");
} else {
    // Create a new device
    NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newDevice setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
    [newDevice setValue:self.versionTextField.text forKey:@"version"];
    [newDevice setValue:self.companyTextField.text forKey:@"company"];
    NSLog(@"else");
}

NSError *error = nil;
// Save the object to persistent store
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Please also properly format your code.

Answer (score 2):

> NSCFConstantString text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Error suggests that somewhere you are trying to set `text` on `NSString`.

So, check your code and see that if you are accessing `text` property on `NSString` because `NSString` doesn't have `text` property and correct it.

Hope this will help!